# php and xml error

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml file generated by my web service,
I now want to display some information from the xml

all tags in the xml are in the same level, there is no hierarchy.

However, I have these tags on either side of the document, namely:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"><xmlresponse>
```

And:

```
</xmlresponse></xml>
```

afin d'utiliser une balise  et de l'afficher j'ai donc le code suivant:

```
<?php
$document_xml = new DomDocument(); 
$resultat_html = '';
$document_xml->load('tmp/'.$_GET['n_doss'].'.xml'); 
//echo $elements = $document_xml->getElementsByTagName('rating');


$title = $document_xml->xpath('rating');
echo trim($title[0]);
?>
```

However, I am forwarding an error message saying:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument :: xpath ()
```

I do not know how to solve it.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `xml` file is valid and it loads correctly by `DomDocument`. And why you don't use `SimpleXML` library ? It also supports `XPath` expressions the following way:

```
$simplexml= new SimpleXMLElement($xml); // loading RAW XML string `$xml` retrieved from WebService
$items =  $simplexml->xpath('/rating'); // querying DOM to retrieve <rating></rating> from the root of of the structure
echo $items[0]; // getting result
```

**NOTE:** `DomDocument` doesn't have `xpath` method. Use `query` method to apply `XPath` expression to the *object* using `DomXPath` like this:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->load('tracks.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$query = '//distance[. > "15000"]';
$distances = $xpath->query($query);
```

Comment: I just would like to display some elements from the xml file.

xml file is valid because it is generated by my web service

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski, use `DOMXPath` to apply `XPath` expressions to already loaded `DomDocument`.

Comment: now it says:

 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'SimpleXMLElement::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given' in C:\wamp\www\NEOGETCASH\GESTIONNAIRE\DOSSIERS\creditsafe.php on line 31
( ! ) Exception: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\wamp\www\NEOGETCASH\GESTIONNAIRE\DOSSIERS\creditsafe.php on line 31

Comment: I've written this

`<?php

$document_xml = new DomDocument(); 
$resultat_html = '';
$document_xml->load('tmp/'.$_GET['n_doss'].'.xml'); 
//echo $elements = $document_xml->getElementsByTagName('rating');

$simplexml= new SimpleXMLElement($document_xml); // loading XML to the object
$items =  $simplexml->xpath('/rating'); // querying DOM
echo $items[0]; 

?>`

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski, `$xml` transferred to the `SimpleXMLElement` should be RAW XML string, not an object.

Comment: now it says `Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<'`
`Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: tmp/120015660012.xml in `
`Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: ^ in C:`
` Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'`
`! ) Exception: String could not be parsed as XML i`

Comment: Again Check Your XML bec, error `'String could not be parsed as XML'` is obviously says that smth. is not right with your XML.

Comment: how can I show you my xml? here it's limited whith the caracteres. oh I know here is my xml file http://bit.ly/OHybZA

Comment: oh this links is broken here an other one http://www.2shared.com/document/YZWT8rRE/120015660012.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the `DOMDocument` has an `xpath` method. Instead you can use the `DOMXPath` class.

Try this:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document_xml);
$ratings = $xpath->query('rating');
```

Comment: niw it says to me

 Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string in C